# Is it possible to choose which file tensorflow is installed in?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, pycharm, tensorflow2.0

I've been getting a warning when trying to install tensorflow on my windows pc, through the command prompt:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\RCG\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\com_github_grpc_grpc\\src\\core\\ext\\filters\\client_channel\\lb_policy\\grpclb\\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
```

When looking this up, I found out that windows can't accept file paths longer than 250 words or so.

I've tried installing through anaconda but then I get a different error in pycharm: module not found (I've used an anaconda environment and tried installing through pycharm packages)

So I'm wondering if I can manually decide the file path for TensorFlow so windows will accept it.

Python was installed through microsoft store (otherwise pip wouldn't work)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The easy solution would be installing the Python interpreter outside `AppData`. Just install Python in a folder that's closer to the root of the HDD.

Comment: thank you, I think it should be working now